# oledb Source not returning data in ssis

Tags: t-sql, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, bids

I have worked on an SSIS solution wherein I migrated the package from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SSDT 2014. After migration, I faced the below issue:

We have 4 OLeDB sources in the Dataflow task. Though all of them get executed without any error, two of them return 0 rows. Upon further inspection of the underlying query at the corresponding OLeDB source, I found that it returns data when I execute it on SQL query window. 
The frustrating part is that I don't face this issue every time. 2 out of 10 times, this happens.

[image]

Comment: Can you add more information as this is very vague. Can you maybe give examples of the SQL you execute, what environment does this happen in i.e. DEV or LIVE etc. Are you using Package or Project deployment model? is this all in one package/dataflow

Comment: yes Eugene..Sql have  a select statement with some joins.environment  is Dev. yes all in one package/Dataflow. i executed it from packag.e

Comment: Are you sure that the data is static. There should be no reason for this to just fail sometimes. Do you have an time based logic or using a shared database with other devs that could cause this? Also are you using project or package connections strings? Also do you share a connection string for all sources or do they have their own?

Comment: yes there is no time based logic data is static and database is separate.I am using dynamic connection string which is package based.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error? What do you mean by dynamic connection string, as in you use an expression to set it? Does it fail 2 out of 10 executions in succession or do you just mean as you develop etc it sometimes fail? This is very difficult to diagnose with the information provided

Comment: As you seen the image 2 of them return data and 2 task run successfully but not returning any data.Nothing is fail in the package.

Comment: Do they have no rows every time? If you run the same queries in SSMS at the same time do you get results? Do you have any parameters that are set from outside your query?

Comment: Yes i get the result everytime.there are no parameter in the query

Comment: You need to rerun it until you can reproduce the error. For every run, use SQL Profiler, or my favourite, `sp_WhoIsActive` to observe the query when it has run. Compare the query with data to the query without data when it has run. Can you post the SQL that you are using?